# Jquery open div onclick bottom button

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div id="Slider-First Slider-Common">

    <div class="Slider-Item Slider-First">
        <img src="img/pet1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="Slider-Item Slider-Second">
        <img src="img/pet2.jpg"/>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="Bottom-Button">

<a href="">Click</a>

</div>
```

Here i have like above... onclik slider-first should open, then if i click in that page slider-second should open how ... i need jquery solution for this. Per page only one slider item should there

Comment: have you tried something .. ?

Comment: You should try something before asking or at least googling it! This question has been asked a bazillion times. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id="Slider-First Slider-Common"]').hide();

    $(".Bottom-Button a").click(function() {
        $('[id="Slider-First Slider-Common"]').show(); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

P.S. You shouldn't use spaces in element `id`'s.

**EDIT** Just read your question again, will need to make some amendments.

```
$('.Slider-Item').hide();


$('.Bottom-Button a').on('click',function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.Slider-First').show();
    return false;
});

$('.Slider-First').on('click',function(){
    $('.Slider-First').hide();
    $('.Slider-Second').show();
    return false;
});
```

**FURTHER EDIT**

```
$('.Slider-Item').hide();


$('.Bottom-Button a').on('click',function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('.Slider-First').show();
    return false;
});

$('.Slider-Item').on('click',function(){
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    }

    return false;
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9p9sg/

Comment: This ok but i having from slider-first to slider-eight, totlay 8 images. each image in one div(sider-common). so that bottom link is in each page. in slider first page if i click that button that time slider second should open... that time all other slider items should invisble. then in slider second page if i click that button that time slider-three needs to open.. so on

Comment: Spaces are not defined as characters in id's and classes. It is a seperator. `Slider-First` and `Slider-Common` are two distinguished id's.

Comment: thank you so much.. but after opening i needs to click that bottom button only. i need not click slider-item.

Answer (score 0):

As per I understood following JQ should work for you... I think you want to show the Image on click... right ??

you can try this one:

```
$('.Slider-Item').on('click',function(){
 $('.Slider-Item:visible').slideUp(200);
 $(this).slideDown(200);
});
```

If you want anything else comment....

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

HTML

```
<div id="Slider-First Slider-Common">

    <div class="Slider-Item Slider-First">
        <img src="img/pet1.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="Slider-Item Slider-Second">
        <img src="img/pet2.jpg"/>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="Bottom-Button">

<a href="#" class="click_me">Click</a>

</div>
```

Jquery Part

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".Slider-Item Slider-First").hide();
 $(".Slider-Item Slider-Second").hide();
 $(".click_me").click(function(){
  $(".Slider-Item Slider-First").show(); 
 });
 $(".Slider-Item Slider-First").click(function(){
  $(".Slider-Item Slider-Second").show(); 
 });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanking you.. It is helping more. but here i dont want click any Slider-Item. For clicking purpose only bottom button i am having. so after opening slider-first, should open slider-second,slider-third and so on ... onclick that button

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference, feel free to update this code just replace those text with `<img src="...."/>`.

**css:**

```
#slider{list-style-type:none}
.slider-item{display:none;}
.slider-show{display:block;}
```

**html:**

```
<ul id="slider">
    <li class="slider-item">a</li>
    <li class="slider-item">b</li>
    <li class="slider-item">c</li>
    <li class="slider-item">d</li>
    <li class="slider-item slider-show">e</li>
</ul>
<a href="">Click</a>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var indexLength = $('.slider-item').length-1;
    var currentIndex = $('.slider-item:visible').index();
    var log = $('#log');
    $('.slider-item:visible').hide();    
    if(currentIndex<indexLength){         
         currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
    }
    else{
        currentIndex = currentIndex - indexLength;        
    }
    log.append(currentIndex);
    $('.slider-item:eq('+currentIndex+')').show();
    return false;
});
```

I created a fiddle for you, [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/aGp8n/).

Comment: @Soliyappan just removed the unnecessary code. purposely for debugging only.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="slider">
<li class="slider-item">a</li>
<li class="slider-item">b</li>
<li class="slider-item">c</li>
<li class="slider-item">d</li>
<li class="slider-item slider-show">e</li>
```

Click

The above code is my flexslider.Slider working nice but for this slider i need to make bottom controls to jump particular sliders like bellow (slider pager)

```
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>
```